# How can I create a file with invalid Windows timestamps?

Tags: windows, filesystem-corruption, timestamp, file-corruption

I'd like to create a file with an invalid created/modified/accessed timestamp. To be invalid it should be a date and time before 12:00 midnight January 1, 1601 C.E. UTC

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: So that I can test that the application I'm writing can handle corrupt timestamps gracefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for a tool called [Timestomp](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Timestomp)

> The software's goal is to allow for the deletion or modification of
>   time stamp-related information on files.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.

File time is used in Windows API through the [FILETIME Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28VS.85%29.aspx), described as:

> Contains a 64-bit value representing
>   the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

As negative values are not supported, the above date is the starting limit.

Conclusion: Your code which tests for earlier dates will never be challenged.

Comment: The "touch" command in Linux can create such a file, but under Windows it is recognized as being created today. (Tested with FAT32 Flashdrive and Win XP)